# What is the difference between Complete and Chronicles mode in Steam's release of Ys I & II Chronicles+?

Tags: ys-1-and-2-chronicles-+

[image]

I installed [Ys I and Ys II Chronicles+](http://store.steampowered.com/app/223810/) (by downloading the games separately on Steam and then [linking them together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvzd5.png) while [this lady stares at you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JfFC.png) and [I don't even](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFn39.png).)

When I try and start the game, however, a somewhat strategically-placed dialogue asks me if I want to play it in "Chronicles" or "Complete" mode. What's the difference?

Comment: I honestly have no idea if I should tag this question [tag:ys-1], [tag:ys-2], both, neither, I dunno. Please send help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ys I and II were each remastered and rereleased in 2009 and 2011 (and again most recently as Chronicles+), each time with new art assets. Instead of doing yet another art overhaul in Chronicles+, both of the previous sets of art assets were included. The menu lets you switch between the 2009 art and the 2011 art. Otherwise the games are the same.

The newer art assets aren't strictly better, just in a different style — the older is more classic JRPG, while the newer is in a more polished manga style. You can try both to see which you prefer, assuming the difference in the art is something that matters to you. I admit, it's a really important-looking menu for such a minor difference.